# Ubuntu can't login after disabling auto login

Tags: login, 15.04, auto-login

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 and after disabling auto login the Ubuntu screen loads up and then its just a black screen. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a shell or terminal. Use this:

```
ctrl + alt + F1-F7
```

Log in and try to launch the GUI with this command:

`sudo lightdm` or `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: When I enter that it says "failed to load configuration from /etc/lightdm/lighdm.conf: key file contained line ****XX*XXX which is not a key-value pair, group or comment" any thoughts? I've tried both commands and it doesn't work. The second command after use says that there is no such file or directory